# Handle multiple ajax request & response

Tags: ajax

I want to handle multiple ajax responses. Each request will take different time to complete.

Some request might be success and some might be failure . How to know which request is

success or failure ?

can anyone help me out to this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution,

```
    var requestCount = 5,
    requestComplete = 0,
    onAjaxComplete = function () {
        requestComplete++;

        if (requestComplete >= requestCount) {
            // all ajax requests complete
            alert('Complete');
        }
    };

for (var i=0; i<requestCount; i++) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        // @todo: ajax request config
        success: function () {onAjaxComplete();},
        failure: function () {onAjaxComplete();}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery `$.ajax(..)`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  },
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    },
    200: function() {
      alert('OK !');
    }
  }
});
```

or generar Error callback `error : {}`